# Is there a way to unit test whether or not view controller is pushed in the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uikit

let's say I have this code as an example

```
finall class SomeTests: XCTTestCase {
    private var coordinator: SomeCoordinator!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setup()
        coordinator = SomeCoordinator()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
        coordinator = nil
    }

    func testStartPushesCustomViewController() {
         coordinator.start()
         XCTAssertTrue(coordinator.navController.viewControllers.last is CustomViewcontroller)

        XCTAssert // -> make an assertion that the CustomViewController is pushed on the main thread
    }
}
```

is it possible to find a way to write a unit test where we can prove that the view controller is pushed in the main thread?

Comment: Seems like a strange test. Do you expect your coordinator to do background thread processing?

Comment: I have seen a few bugs where a controller not being pushed in the main thread was an issue. this is not a coordinator-related question though. In this example, I choose to use it because of a force of habit.